# Pass specific structure to function in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have been writing a program in C to draw characters on a display using a PIC.

I have a number of structures containing the symbols and metadata for different fonts and I am struggling to work out how to pass them to the function that draws the symbol in the display buffer. The code I have currently will not compile.

So far I have structures that follow this format in a header file:

```
struct Arial
{
    char symbol[1000] = {...};
    int info[32][3] = {...};
};

struct Courier
{
    char symbol[1000] = {...};
    int info[32][3] = {...};
};

struct Calibri
{
    char symbol[1000] = {...};
    int info[32][3] = {...};
};
```

Ideally in the rest of my code I would like to pass a reference to one of the structures in the arguments of the display function so it knows which font to use. I am having trouble getting my head around how to do this and I'm getting confused.

For example if I wanted to use the font Arial to print the 10th character in the Arial structure:

```
void display_function(struct *font_name, int letter)
{
    int letter_start = font_name->info[letter][0];
    char letter_data = font_name->symbol[letter_start];

    // Draws to buffer here
}

void main()
{
    display_function(&Arial, 10);
}
```

Any help on the way forward would be much appreciated. I have tried searching for other similar questions but can't find one that I have been able to work out.

Comment: What problems are you facing when using your current function `display_function()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `struct` definition does not by itself create a variable.  It only defines a type and its members.  Because of that, you can't specify initializers in a struct definition.

You need to create variables of that type.  Then you can initialize them.  In this case you only need one type and three variables of that type.

```
struct font
{
    char symbol[1000];
    int info[32][3];
};

struct font Arial = { 
    "abcdefg...",
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        ...
    }
};

struct font Courier = { 
    "qwerty...",
    {
        { 9, 8, 7 },
        { 2, 3, 4 },
        ...
    }
};


void display_function(struct font *font_name, int letter)
{
    int letter_start = font_name->info[letter][0];
    char letter_data = font_name->symbol[letter_start];

    // Draws to buffer here
}

void main()
{
    display_function(&Arial, 10);
}
```

Comment: I find that the concept of structure variables sadly glossed over in online tutorials; for example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm)